# Multiple upstream faye websocket servers with nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, thin, faye

I would like to cluster my faye websocket server. A single server works well but I want to be prepared to scale. 
My first attempt is to start a few thin servers on different sockets and then add them to the upstream for my server in nginx.

The bayeux messages are distributed amongst the clusters but chrome dev tools shows about 16
websocket 101 connections with connection closed in the `frame` tab of the `networking` panel:

```
Connection Close Frame (Opcode 8)
Connection Close Frame (Opcode 8, mask)
```

And a whole bunch of `/meta/connect` and `/meta/handshake` on the server side for all of the faye instances.

An excerpt:

```
D, [2013-11-15T15:34:50.215631 #5344] DEBUG -- : {"channel"=>"/meta/connect",  "clientId"=>"q7odwfbovudiw87dg0jke3xbrg51tui", "connectionType"=>"callback-polling", "id"=>"p"}
D, [2013-11-15T15:34:50.245012 #5344] DEBUG -- : {"channel"=>"/meta/connect", "clientId"=>"ckowb5vz9pnbh7jwomc8h0qsk8t0nus", "connectionType"=>"callback-polling", "id"=>"r"}
D, [2013-11-15T15:34:50.285460 #5344] DEBUG -- : {"channel"=>"/meta/handshake", "version"=>"1.0", "supportedConnectionTypes"=>["callback-polling"], "id"=>"u"}
D, [2013-11-15T15:34:50.312919 #5344] DEBUG -- : {"channel"=>"/meta/handshake", "version"=>"1.0", "supportedConnectionTypes"=>["callback-polling"], "id"=>"w"}
D, [2013-11-15T15:34:50.356219 #5344] DEBUG -- : {"channel"=>"/meta/handshake", "version"=>"1.0", "supportedConnectionTypes"=>["callback-polling"], "id"=>"y"}
D, [2013-11-15T15:34:50.394820 #5344] DEBUG -- : {"channel"=>"/meta/handshake", "version"=>"1.0", "supportedConnectionTypes"=>["callback-polling"], "id"=>"10"}
```

Starting the thin servers (each in its own terminal):

```
thin start -C config/thin/development.yml -S /tmp/faye.1.sock
thin start -C config/thin/development.yml -S /tmp/faye.2.sock
thin start -C config/thin/development.yml -S /tmp/faye.3.sock
```

My thin config:

```
---
environment: development
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 100
require: []
wait: 30
# socket: /tmp/faye.sock
daemonize: false
rackup: config.ru
```

My NGINX config:

```
upstream thin_cluster {
  server unix:/tmp/faye.1.sock fail_timeout=0;
  server unix:/tmp/faye.2.sock fail_timeout=0;
  server unix:/tmp/faye.3.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  # listen 443;
  server_name ~^push\.mysite\.dev(\..*\.xip\.io)?$;
  charset UTF-8;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  # ssl on;
  # ssl_certificate  /var/www/heypresto/certificates/cert.pem;
  # ssl_certificate_key /var/www/heypresto/certificates/key.pem;
  # ssl_protocols TLSv1 SSLv3;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://thin_cluster;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    break;
  }
}
```

Thought it was too good to be true to put more upstreams for websockets and it would just work, but it seems so close...

**EDIT:** I've realised that this is probably not going to work and I should probably create N servers (push1.mysite.dev, push2.mysite.dev etc) and have the backend tell the frontend which one to connect.

Still If there are any thoughts out there...

Comment: Same issue with websocket-rails.  Can you fill in the reason you expect this to fail?  I'd think it should be fine?

Comment: The complexity comes in when you publish a message how do you publish to the correct faye server so that it can send on the message to the connected clients. I suppose, a global publish to all faye servers would work.

Comment: As for the original Opcode 8 mask error, I would like to know the explanation for that.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but you can use multiple faye servers by using the faye-redis plugin. Normally faye keeps all connection state details in memory in its own process, so one faye won't know if someone is listening to a different faye server. Faye redis instead stores state in redis which can be shared by as many faye servers as can be handled by your redis server. So if using redis for storage a message published to a faye server at push1.mysite.dev would still be delivered to a client listening to push2.mysite.dev.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! Any chance you could add a full answer?